# Exporting mtl files from 3ds max problem

Tags: graphics, 3dsmax

I'm having a small problem with exporting mtl files in 3ds max. I would like to use an obj + its material library in an opengl program. The model gets exported just fine, but I loose all the reflective/refractive parameters of my materials when I export them (colors and such seem to be fine so it finds them just not completely but all materials get changed to standard). I tried exporting materials from the scene and from the mat. library aswell with the same results. Could anyone help me how to keep the reflective parameters of materials after exporting?

Comment: if it does not include this information the way you export now, then I would assume you could just write a function for exporting the needed data out to a new ascii file, which you then read back in to your opengl program, in addition to the files you are exporting now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With what should I write the function for this? I know thers a c++ based MaxSDK that supports writing plugins but I'm not familiar with it. Is that ok for the function I would like to create or do you advise a different 'framework'?

Comment: the easiest way to do this is with maxscript. and since it's material oriented (and not mesh export) it will be very fast.
It's not hard to write a simple script that outputs your data.

but I need to know what type of material do you have in your scene in max? (is it "standard material" shader?) or something different?

Comment: Either standard material or raytrace (still havent decided which one to use) with a raytrace reflection map added to it.

Comment: and exactly what parameters do you need to be exported?

Comment: a sample file would be great, you can send it to me directly. I've made a script that parses the standard and raytrace materials, but I need to know the last parameters  \ texture parameters that you want to export.

Comment: Sent you a sample file. I would like to export the reflective parameter of an object so that it still retains it in another file format (obj/mtl or 3ds) as currently it seems to get lost after the export.

Comment: what I'm confused about is what you mean when you say 'reflective parameter', is the spinner values what you need? (reflective amount spinner value?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in the email you use Glut as API. there are several tutorials for this,
I initially thought you used a engine, and just needed some values.
But you needed more then this.

To use reflection \ environment mapping in opengl you need a shader that supports this.

So what you need to do is to implement a reflection shader, and pass the bitmap into your shader.

In the sample file it worked fine for rendered image (because 3dsmax supports it's own raytrace materials), but this does not get exported in any way.

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort you put into this and sorry if the informatiom I gave was a bit unclear here and there, only started this entire 3d development stuff 2 weeks ago and am still a bit confused about some stuff :)